# How can I compare strings as unordered elements of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, indexof

I'm still learning js and I'm having some difficulties understanding what mistake I'm making in this exercise. The exercise is one from FCC: it asks to return true if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.

So far I've tried several methods, but the last one I feel is the closest I can get. I've came up with this so far (mind that I'm trying the code before inserting it in the function of FCC):

```
    let array = ["floor", "for"];
    
    let lowercase = array.map(name => name.toLowerCase());
    let string1 = lowercase.slice(0, 1).toString();
    let string2 = lowercase.slice(1).toString();

    let arraysplit1 = string1.split("").sort();
    let arraysplit2 = string2.split("").sort();

    for (let i = 0; i < arraysplit2.length; i ++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arraysplit1.length; j ++){
      if (arraysplit1.indexOf(arraysplit2[i]) != -1){
         console.log("ok");
        
        
        }
    else {
        console.log("not ok");
        
    }
    }

    }
```

As you can see, first  I've turned everything into lowerCase (in case one of the 2 values has some uppercase). Then sliced and stringed into 2 different arrays (most probably there is a way to solve this without creating 2 different arrays, but I felt more comfortable dividing the 2 words). Splitted and sorted the various letters (sorting actually useless, since I would like to check everyone of them anyway).
Now the real problem is in the 2 for loops and in the following if statement: it seems I cannot get the logic of those right, since is not working.

I would appreciate your comments on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you allowed to use [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loops here. You just need to iterate over the characters in the second word and check whether each is present in the first.

If you encounter a character whose `firstWord.indexOf(c)` is -1 the answer is no/false, otherwise it's yes/true. You could use [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to simplify your code a bit, but either way works.

If you turn this into a function you could have it return true or false for any two words, which would clarify the expected behavior and encapsulate it for ease of use:

```js
function hasAllChars (wordA, wordB) {
  // ...
  return true;
}

console.log(hasAllChars("floor", "for")); // true

if (hasAllChars("floor", "for")) {
  // do stuff
}
```

---

### A single for loop

Here's an implementation using a single for loop:

```js
function hasAllChars(wordA, wordB) {
  const charsB = wordB.split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < charsB.length; i++) {
    if (wordA.indexOf(charsB[i]) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(hasAllChars("floor", "for")); // true
console.log(hasAllChars("floor", "fort")); // false
```

---

### Using Array.every:

Here's a simpler implementation using every and indexOf:

```js
function hasAllChars(wordA, wordB) {
  const charsB = wordB.split('');
  return charsB.every(char => wordA.indexOf(char) > -1);
}

console.log(hasAllChars("floor", "for")); // true
console.log(hasAllChars("floor", "fort")); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the exercise asks to return true only if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element. So for example when you have ["floor", "for"], should return "true" since every letter of the word "for" are contained in the word "floor" (but not the entire word "for", since in the first one there is an "L" in between).

Comment: Right. That's what this does. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The example with the single loop was the most helping one: it was needed just loop after all. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to split a string with `[...str]` instead of `str.split('')`. Here's why:

```js
[...'']
//=> ["", "", ""]

// vs

''.split('')
//=> ["\ud83c", "\udf2f", "\ud83c", "\udf2f", "\ud83c", "\udf2f"]
```

You only need to check a letter once. In `'floor'` you only need to check `'o'` once. So you need a set:

```js
new Set([...'floor'])
//=> Set(4) {"f", "l", "o", "r"}

// vs

[...'floor']
//=> ["f", "l", "o", "o", "r"]
```

Assuming `a` can contain all the characters of `b` but is not limited to only those then we can just iterate over `b`:

```js
const check = (a, b) => {
  const as = new Set([...a]);
  const bs = new Set([...b]);
  for (let c of bs) if (!as.has(c)) return false;
  return true;
}

console.log(check("floor", "for"));
console.log(check("floor", "fot"));
console.log(check("", ""));
console.log(check("", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but unfortunately is too advanced for me. Things like .has and Sets are still out of my reach.